# How to synchronously bootstrap an angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

How to synchronously bootstrap an angularjs app

I define a couple constant values on my app object.  Some of these values need to be set via a call to a service and these calls need to complete before any of my controllers are instantiated.

In the example below, I define an array of values on an object named config.  I need to set the value named PostIndexMenuID prior to any of my controllers being instantiated.  How do I do that?

I have tried manually bootstrapping (removing ng-app from the html).  I am not using routing.

Ideally I will not have to learn, download, install, configure, test, and maintain another framework to accomplish this.

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('app', []);
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'config', '$http', controller]);
    app.service('menusService', ['$http', 'config', menusService]);

    // Create config object. Some values are set in app.run

    app.value('config', {
        siteID:             100,
        webRoot:            '',
        apiRoot:            '/api',
        imageRoot:          '/Content/images',
        PostIndexMenuID:    0
    });


    app.run(['$http', 'config','menusService', function ($http, config, menusService) {

        menusService.GetMenuIDByName("PostIndex", function (data) {
            config.PostIndexMenuID = data;  // Need to complete this BEFORE GetPosts on the controller is called
        });

    }]);

    function controller($scope, config, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.Posts = 0;  

        function GetPosts() {
            // In prod we call a service here get posts based on config.PostIndexMenuID
            // for this example just return PostIndexMenuID.  

            vm.Posts = config.PostIndexMenuID;
        };

        GetPosts();  // need to delay calling this until AFTER PostIndexMenuID is set
    };

    function menusService($http, config) {
        this.GetMenuIDByName = function (menuName, callBack) {
            var uri = config.apiRoot + '/menu/GetMenuByName?menuName=' + menuName + '&siteID=' + config.siteID;

            // use a timeout to simulate a slow service for this example and return a dummy value
            var menuID = 99;
            setTimeout(function () {
               callBack(menuID);  
            }, 2000);

        };
    };

})()
```

// html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app" >
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller = "controller as vm">
        <p>PostIndexMenuId is {{ vm.Posts }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a nifty trick in Angular.js whereby you can defer the changing of a route until all promises have been resolved. You may have to restructure your application a little bit to cater for this approach, but I use it myself and it works like a treat!

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function $routeChangeStart(event, next) {

    // Extend the resolution of the route promise to wait for the user authentication
    // process to determine if there's a valid session available.
    next.resolve = angular.extend( next.resolve || {}, {
        authenticating: api.isSession
    });

});
```

By using the `next.resolve` you're extending Angular's sequence of promises that are resolved before a route change is considered a success. In the above case, as long as `api.isSession` returns a promise then everything will work wonderfully.

As soon as the `api.isSession` promise has been resolved, then the route change will succeed, and in your case, your controller will be loaded.

Comment: Inside of your `app.run`.

Comment: routChangeStart is never called. I am loading angular-route.js, modified app.run to inject $rootScope.  next.resolve is never assigned a value.

Comment: also injected ngRoute into the module.